# Instalacion bitbucket, jira

Tags: linux, jira

Como están... Tengo instalado bitbucket y jira en mi servidor, todo correctamente pero no puedo mantener la sesión de los dos al mismo tiempo, ya que si ingreso a Jira se cierra la sesión de Bitbucket de la misma manera sucede con con el Jira. Alguien si pudiera ayudarme a dar solución por favor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seguramente tu problema sea debido al "context-path" de ambas aplicaciones, es un bug conocido de los productos Atlassian y está relacionado con las Cookies (más info [aquí](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/user-is-constantly-logged-out-of-jira-192872663.html)). Seguramente tengas intalado JIRA de tal manera que accedas en un url parecida a esta:
**localhost:8080**

Y bitbucket igual (**localhost:7990**) . Necesitas instalar las aplicaciones en "paths" distintos de la máquina. Por ejemplo:

**localhost:8080/jira**

**localhost:7990/bitbucket**

Debes editar el archivo "server.xml" de tomcat. En el enlace que te pasé más arriba viene explicado.

Espero que sirva!

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta... funciona....